# How to read input with space in java

Tags: java, input, import

I want to take input as an 2d array with space, but my code ignoring the space.

import java.util.Scanner;

class helloworld{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    int m=sc.nextInt();
    int arr[][]=new int[n][m];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++) {
            arr[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
    sc.close();
}
```

}

Output:
[[], [2], [], [], [], [1], [], [], []]

but, my output is..
[[2],[1],........ it's, still taking input, it totally ignoring space.

Comment: That's because you use nextInt() to read data and it ignore spaces... you should read all the line and parse the string or read byte to byte and manage when you hit the first number char.

Comment: Here there's an example of what i told you: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-take-input-from-user-separated-by-space-in-java/

Comment: An int array cannot ever be/output  `[[], [2], [], [], [], [1], [], [], []] `. int is a primtive data type in java that always has a value assigned to it. An int cannot be "nothing" as you want it to be.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're attempting but you might use ```Integer[][]``` and use ```null```  for 'empty'

Comment: Your solution does not ignore spaces. In fact it recognizes one or more whitespace characters as the delimiter between integers. Your definition of two consecutive spaces would be that there is an int inbetween (probably zero), while the Scanner defines no digit as no number and moves on.